# OnClickListener в ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть класс-наследник `ViewPager`, в котором я использую нужный `layout` в методе `instantiateItem()`:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private Context context;

        public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, collection, false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, collection, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.three, collection, false);
                    break;
            }
            collection.addView(view);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "about one";
                case 1:
                    return "about two";
                case 2:
                    return "about three";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужно обработать нажатие на `ImageView`, которая находится в `one.xml`. Но если я обрабатываю нажатие в `onCreate()` текущей `Activity`, то естественным образом вылетает `NullPointerException`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где же должен я обрабатывать нажатие.

Полный код `MainActivity():`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
        img.setOnClickListener(...) // NullPointerException
    }


    public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            private Context context;

            public MyPagerAdapter(Context context) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View view = null;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, collection, false);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, collection, false);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.three, collection, false);
                        break;
                }
                collection.addView(view);
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
                collection.removeView((View) view);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "about one";
                    case 1:
                        return "about two";
                    case 2:
                        return "about three";
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо вешать слушатель нажатий в том методе, где вы загружаете разметку для страницы. Т.е. в `instantiateItem` методе адаптера. Причём искать вьюху надо в переменной оную содержащей, т.е. в `view`. Т.е. дополните код так:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one, collection, false);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
            img.setOnClickListener(...)
            break;
        case 1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, collection, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.three, collection, false);
            break;
    }
    collection.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Юрий, спасибо огромное!
Причем я попробовал таким способом реализовать, но совсем не подумал про `view`, а написал просто `...(ImageView)findViewById(...);`